# Binding SQL data to a datagrid

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Trying to get data from a SQL database to be displayed in a datagrid and it is not being displayed.

Code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Data
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    string SQLSERVER_ID = @""; - Removed the ID and Password intentionally to show this code.
    string SQLDatabaseName = "Data Logging";
    string SQLServerLoginName = "Data User";
    string SQLServerPassword = "";

    public void SQLCmd(string SQLString)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conDatabase = new SqlConnection(String.Format(@"Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Persist Security Info=True;User ID={2};Password={3}", SQLSERVER_ID, SQLDatabaseName, SQLServerLoginName, SQLServerPassword));
            conDatabase.Open();
            SqlCommand cmdDatabase = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Bags (RecordNumber, Date, Time) VALUE ('1', '2014-08-01', '08:00:00')" + SQLString, conDatabase);
            cmdDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conDatabase.Close();
            conDatabase.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception em)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(em.ToString());
        }

    }

    public System.Data.DataTable GetDataTable(string SQLString)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Data.DataTable dtTable = new System.Data.DataTable("dtTable");
            string ConnectionString = String.Format(@"Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Persist Security Info=True;User ID={2};Password={3}", SQLSERVER_ID, SQLDatabaseName, SQLServerLoginName, SQLServerPassword);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlAdpt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM bags ORDER BY RecordNumber, Date, Time", ConnectionString);
            sqlAdpt.Fill(dtTable);
            sqlAdpt.Dispose();
            return dtTable;
        }
        catch (Exception em)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(em.ToString());
            return new System.Data.DataTable();
        }
    }
```

EDIT UP: end-quote was missing in sql query.

I have a SQL database with data inside it but i am unsure of how to get the datagrid to display it, as this should work. Unless i have forgotten to add something. The grid must show data on load.

EDIT: Datagrid Code

```
<DataGrid Name="dtTable" Margin="0,64,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="True"    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" CanUserResizeColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="_Record Number" Binding="{Binding RecordNumber}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="_Date" Binding="{Binding Date}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="_Time" Binding="{Binding Time}"/>                   
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Bags_Data.Properties.Settings.BagsConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=*****;Initial Catalog=&quot;Bags&quot;;User ID=***;Password=*****"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you ever tried to bind this results in your `.DataSource` property?

Comment: where are your DataGrid binding code?

Comment: Edited. I don't believe it is making a connection to the DB as there are records inside it.

Comment: @zen_1991 you should bind the data to datagrid in the code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up abandoning datagrid and opted for listview instead which i managed to get working rather quickly and it displays the data from SQL on window load.

I added:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowData();
    }

    private void ShowData()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(String.Format(@"Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Persist Security Info=True;User ID={2};Password={3}", SQLSERVER_ID, SQLDatabaseName, SQLServerLoginName, SQLServerPassword));
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Bags", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
        da.Fill(dt);
        listView1.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;
    }
```

Removed the GetDataTable function.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're presuming that because the DataGrid is called dtTable and your System.Data.DataTable is called dtTable that something behind the scenes will wire the two up for you or that they somehow reference one another. This is not the case. You will need to implement code on Load that will call your GetDataTable function setting the resulting DataTable equal to the ItemSource property of the DataGrid. You should also investigate Binding using the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

What i suggest you do to get this working is to rename your datagrid so things will be much easier to see:

```
<DataGrid Name="RecordsDataGrid" Margin="0,64,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="True"    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" CanUserResizeColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="_Record Number" Binding="{Binding RecordNumber}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="_Date" Binding="{Binding Date}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="_Time" Binding="{Binding Time}"/>                   
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

In you code behind, create a list of Records and fill it with the data in your table using dataAdapter, then you can bind this to your datagrid:

```
RecordsDataGrid.ItemsSource = YourListOfRecords;
```